# How to save fetched filenames in csv?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to save the file in csv but unable to do it. That's the code and it is not working that I want.

```
import os
import csv

FOLDER_PATH = '/home/bilal/Documents/Books/English/'

DirectoryFiles = os.listdir(FOLDER_PATH)
# print(DirectoryFiles)
with open('new_names.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in FOLDER_PATH:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: What is not working with the code?

Comment: I am trying to write all the fetched files in csv but it is not working.

Comment: use `for line in DirectoryFiles:` instead of `for line in FOLDER_PATH:`? Why do you iterate the `FOLDER_PATH ` and write its letters into your csv if you want the files?!?

Comment: yes i understand it isn't working but its best if you can tell us exactly what isn't working or the stack trace the code is producing when you run it. @PatrickArtner comment could most likely solve it but without this extra info its hard to know

Comment: Another problem I am facing is the problem of delimiter, **comma** or **blank_space** is appearing in every word. How to get rid of this?

Comment: your issue here is that file names aren't suitable to CSV format its just a list of files you need some sort of tabular data similar to a dataframe or excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason a comma is separating each letter in the file name is because you are using `csv.writer` which takes each input i.e. the file name and seperates them with a comma if what you are wanting to do is write the files to one line for each file name then all you need to do is this.

```
import os
import csv

FOLDER_PATH = "'/home/bilal/Documents/Books/English/'"

DirectoryFiles = os.listdir(FOLDER_PATH)

with open('new_names.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in DirectoryFiles:
        new_file.write(line + ','+ '\n')
```

This will create a one column csv of the file names in the directory with no header.